# How to shift "Date Created" property of a file by a given number of days and hours?

Tags: vba

I am looking for a solution how to change file's property "Date Created". Preferably in VBA since it is the only programming language I more or less able to code with.

I have hundreds of photos taken from my last vacations. And I have noticed that date in my camera settings is wrong. It is set to be December 2014. So the real date on all pictures is shifted back by 216 days, 16 hours and 25 minutes.

How can I possibly open all pictures in a given directory one by one and change "Date Created" property by given number of days and hours? Any hints, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are freeware tools that can help you with this task, but if you want to do it for fun, you can achive this by importing [SetFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx) in your VBA code and then call it for each file in your directory. 
To get started, you can find an example [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FileTimes.htm)